# New designed footer has an issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, footer

I see a new footer style, but the CC-Wiki logo is trying to escape from the footer.

> [image]

Can we fix this? Or it is by design?

Comment: Apart from this, nice new footer! The categories are really useful.

Comment: This is almost certainly by design.

Comment: @DanielDaranas Why? It does not seem to happen on SO or other SX sites or their metas.

Comment: Actually, it looks pretty nice to me. 99% by design, but if it's not then I hope they don't "fix" it.

Comment: IMO it needs a tiny bit of white space below the text so it's not right up against the browser chrome.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett what browser still has chrome at the bottom? besides, the whilespace should be the same gray as the footer, not random white bleeding in from the rest of the design.

Comment: @BenBrock: I'm on chrome and there is white below the grey already (as in the screenshot above) so IMO it's not "random". Ok, maybe browser chrome is the wrong words, basically it's touching the windows start bar. :)

Comment: We have a footer?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment - Yeh [we have](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/footer) :)

Comment: Noooooooo. MY PRETTY SQUARES! How will I find sites by color now!?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, not intentional...

I completely missed this as our dev and local environments has some additional stuff in the footer (just a drop-down that lets us switch site themes). This obscured the CSS issue, so I only saw it now.

I just pushed a fix.

Comment: Is this why meta went offline for a second here?

Comment: @Manishearth - Probably - a redeploy would do that.

Comment: Thank you for changing a footer style. Anyone can find an appropriate site easily now.

Comment: @Oded: Ah. -1 for blowing up meta :P

Comment: While you're at it, there's no category called "Other" so the "more" under OTHER points to `http://stackexchange.com/sites#other` which just redirect to `http://stackexchange.com/sites#users` (all sites).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - True enough. Shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Manishearth - No more deploys for you. You can stay on the old and inferior code base ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - sorted.

Comment: Cheers, no more "more"!

Comment: Are the little colored boxes gone for good?  I kind of like those as a visual cue. (I can post this as a separate question if you think it's a big enough deal to discuss.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard - Yeah, the new design did away with them.

Answer (score 3):

That's caused due to the flair being floated. Adding `overflow: hidden` to the `#footer`, or a clearfix can solve the issue.

Though, I'm not sure that it *is* an issue, it does look nice.