# When viewing with an accessibility feature, the new footer breaks

Tags: support, design, user-interface, footer

I use Chrome browser (most recent stable version) running Windows 7 on laptop PCs with 17 to 18 inch displays. At 200% zoom, the new footer breaks in an especially annoying way, due to the resulting cream colored typeface on an identical cream colored background. Note that the footer regains usability at 175% magnification, and the issue disappears completely at 150%.

[image: broken footer on MSO with 200% magnification and horizontal scroll on PC]

I don't expect perfection from SO and Meta.SO, even though I regularly get exactly that: A flawlessly accessible website at any magnification or enlarged font size or kerning setting. The new top bar is not quite right either, but it is usable. Contrast is maintained, regardless of magnification. I am grateful!

I believe that this may be a different issue, or have a different solution, than the similar questions which pertain more specifically to **mobile** view,

1. **[Meta and Stack Overflow footer broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209347/meta-and-stack-overflow-footer-broken)**
2. **[CC-logo position is incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209254/cc-logo-position-is-incorrect)**
3. **[New designed footer has an issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177455/new-designed-footer-has-an-issue)**. Yes, the `"CC Wiki logo is trying to escape from the footer"` (very cute wording :o) here too, but that is not the central focus of my question.

Comment: I can reproduce the same problem on Firefox 26.0